# How to implement join-fields with Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.0

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.0 and I would like to establish a parent-child-relationship between my entities. I found out that `@JoinTypeRelation` comes with version 4.1.X, but unfortunately, I am stuck with 4.0.0. The official documentation does not have any information about how to implement join-fields, but I hope there is still a way to do it.

In order to give some more detailed information: Since types are no longer supported in ES 7.6.2, I merged my two entities, parent and child, into a single class which holds either parent or child information, but never both.

```
@Document(indexName = "my_index")
public class ParentOrChild {

    @Id
    private String _id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String someParentProperty;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String someChildProperty;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Now I would like to create a join-field so that entities that represent a child can reference another entitiy that represents a parent. My goal is to later find parent entities by searching for properties of their children like this:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "has_child" : {
            "type" : "_doc",
            "query" : {
                "fuzzy" : {
                    "someChildProperty" : "value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any hints you can give me.

Thanks and kind regards,
ElasticsearchLearner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that joins are very expensive and I should avoid them by denormalizing my data. I will do that, which solves this problem for me.